# How to make a matrix from the results of the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I am working with Python in Spyder IDEA.

I have a matrix that I need to populate with results from a for loop. I am trying to save the results from the for loop in a list.

Each result is in matrix form and different from each other. In the end I need to find differences between results.

This is the code I have so far:

```
planning_time = 3
gen_res=numpy.zeros([30,4])
gen_resfinal=[]

for p in range(planning_time):
 for i in range(30):
        for j in range(4):
            gen_res[i,j]=value(m.gen[i,j])
    
    gen_resfinal.append(gen_res)
```

So far I have this:

[image: Example from Spyder IDEA]

But as you can see all the values are the same where from the rest of the code I am sure that they shouldn't be.

I am guessing that just last value that comes from for loop is displayed and added and values before are not.

What am I missing?

---

So I think I should have mentioned this:

The for loop with p is used to run an optimization problem. For different p's, different parameters are used in the optimization.

The i and j for loop I'm not sure about. I know that I need to store the results (which for each optimization is a 30x4 matrix) so I can compare them later.

My thought was to use the append(gen_res) to store the matrices after each other in a list.

Comment: You're reusing the same gen_res over and over, and each time.  Move the line `gen_res = numpy.zeros(..)` after `for p....:`

Comment: I tried this but it created the same result

Comment: Why do you expect 3 different results when you run the same code 3 times? `value(m.gen[i,j])` will return the same value every time you call it with the same combination of `i` and `j`.

Comment: So in each for loop, I am running an optimization that I did not show here. The optimization uses different variables depending on p, so I will have different optimization results.

Comment: `m.gen[i,j]` - what is returned by this code?